# Processing big list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

So I'm trying to solve a challenge and have come across a dead end. My solution works when the list is small or medium but when it is over 50000. It just "time out"

```
a = int(input().strip())
b = list(map(int,input().split()))


result = []
flag = []

for i in range(len(b)):
    temp = a - b[i]
    if(temp >=0 and temp in flag):
        if(temp<b[i]):
            result.append((temp,b[i]))
        else:
            result.append((b[i],temp))
        flag.remove(temp)
    else:
        flag.append(b[i])
    result.sort()


for i in result:
    print(i[0],i[1])
```

Where

a = 10

and b = [ 2, 4 ,6 ,8, 5 ]

Solution sum any two element in **b** which matches **a**

**Edit: ** Updated full code

Comment: Just an idea: Sort list first, go through it and check for each item with `bisect` if matching second element of sum is present. Oh, a simple set may do as well.

Comment: Plz first fix your indentation.

Comment: When you say "the list", are you referring to `b`, or something else? And what is `flag`? Another list? About the same size as `b`?

Answer (score 1):

`flag` is a list, of potentially the same order of magnitude as `b`. So, when you do `temp in flag` that's a linear search: it has to check every value in `flag` to see if that value is `== temp`. So, that's 50000 comparisons. And you're doing that once per loop in a linear walk over `b`. So, your total time is quadratic: `50,000 * 50,000 = 2,500,000,000`. (And `flag.remove` is *also* linear time.)

If you replace `flag` with a set, you can test it for membership (and remove from it) in constant time. So your total time drops from quadratic to linear, or `50,000` steps, which is a lot faster than 2 billion:

```
flagset = set(flag)
for i in range(len(b)):
    temp = a - b[i]
    if(temp >=0 and temp in flagset):
        if(temp<b[i]):
            result.append((temp,b[i]))
        else:
            result.append((b[i],temp))
        flagset.remove(temp)
    else:
        flagset.add(b[i])
flag = list(flagset)
```

If `flag` needs to retain duplicate values, then it's a multiset, not a set, which means you can implement with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
flagset = collections.Counter(flag)
for i in range(len(b)):
    temp = a - b[i]
    if(temp >=0 and flagset[temp]):
        if(temp<b[i]):
            result.append((temp,b[i]))
        else:
            result.append((b[i],temp))
        flagset[temp] -= 1
    else:
        flagset[temp] += 1
flag = list(flagset.elements())
```

---

In your edited code, you’ve got another list that’s potentially of the same size, `result`, and you’re sorting that list every time through the loop.

Sorting takes log-linear time. Since you do it up to 50,000 times, that’s around `log(50;000) * 50,000 * 50,000`, or around 30 billion steps.

If you needed to keep `result` in order throughout the operation, you’d want to use a logarithmic data structure, like a binary search tree or a skiplist, so you could insert a new element in the right place in logarithmic time, which would mean just 800.000 steps.

But you don’t need it in order until the end. So, much more simply, just move the `result.sort` out of the loop and do it at the end.

Comment: @DanielEuchar Your edited code has a second problem, which you also need to fix, so I updated my answer.